# How do I refer to class linkage dynamically?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have 15 sounds called "Sound1", "Sound2", etc set in linkage properties. I want to dynamically refer to them in a loop. For example, instead of

```
currentMusic = new Sound2();
```

How can I do something like

```
currentMusic = new ("Sound" + i)();
```

Or what would be a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the generated class name to a variable, retrieve the class from the application domain and instantiate the new object. **Beware with exceptions!**

```
var soundClassName:String = "Sound" + i;
var soundClass:Class;
var sound:Sound;

try {
    soundClass = getDefinitionByName(soundClassName) as Class;
    sound = new soundClass();
} catch (re:ReferenceError) {
    trace("Class '" + soundClassName + "' not found");
} catch (te:TypeError) {
    trace("Unable to instantiate the sound object");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the same procedure as you would to load a movie clip or font at runtime.

Assuming you have sounds in your library exported as "sound_0", "sound_1", ..., "sound_9", etc:

```
for(var i:uint = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var soundClass:Class = getDefinitionByName("sound_" + i.toString()) as Class;
    var sound:Sound = new soundClass();
}
```